# when i am adding in UITabBar background image then height increase automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am adding UITabBar controller, But problem is that when i am set background image its Black space from bottom and when  i remove the background image its works fine  .
 I am adding in app delegate

```
  -(void)gotoLoginStoryBoard
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard ;
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *login = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    recentsViewController = [[RecentsViewController alloc]
                             initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    recentsViewController.phoneCallDelegate = self;
    UINavigationController *recentsViewCtrl = [[[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                initWithRootViewController:
                                                recentsViewController]
                                               autorelease];
    recentsViewCtrl.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [recentsViewController release];
    phoneViewController = [[[PhoneViewController alloc]
                            initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
    phoneViewController.phoneCallDelegate = self;
    ContactViewController *contactsViewCtrl = [[[ContactViewController alloc]
                                                init] autorelease];
    contactsViewCtrl.phoneCallDelegate = self;
    VoicemailController *voicemailController = [[VoicemailController alloc]
                                                initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    voicemailController.phoneCallDelegate = self;
    UINavigationController *voicemailNavCtrl = [[[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                 initWithRootViewController:
                                                 voicemailController]
                                                autorelease];
    voicemailNavCtrl.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [voicemailController release];
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                        /*favoritesViewCtrl,*/ login,
                                        phoneViewController, contactsViewCtrl, nil];
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
     [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbarimage.png"]];
    [[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] tabBarItem]setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fill3Copy.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pathCopy4.png"]];
    [[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] tabBarItem]setTitle:@"Contact"];
    [[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] tabBarItem]setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fill3Copy3.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pathCopy5.png"]];
    [[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] tabBarItem]setTitle:@"Group"];
   [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor ]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];

}
```

[image: I have added screen shots from down site its black screen]

Comment: where are you trying to set background image exactly to view controllers background or on the background of UITabbar?

Comment: i am adding in appdelegate u can check my code thanks

Comment: when i am  comment this line working fine    // [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbarimage.png"]];

Comment: only  problem with recent controller number pad and contacts there is no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was missing this line in appellate.

MelpHomeViewController *melpHome = (MelpHomeViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeController"];

Answer (score 0):

First of All check your imagesize.

> from apple documentation the maximum size of a picture on the TabBar
>   are 30x30 (60x60 for the retina display).

I think  it's not possible to take the entire height of the TabBar without strech the image like UIimageview . so, according to me the best solution is to center the image in the TabBar using imageInset.

```
tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, -6, -10);

                        OR


tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
```

Set Imageinsect till image fit to tabbar controller.

For More Detail Check Apple Document below link.

> [**Icon and Image Sizes**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

[image]

[image]

I hope it will helpful for you.